# RxJS not behaving as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working on an Angular 8 application using RxJS 6. I thought I was doing quite well with RxJS, but today I came across something that makes me think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how it works.

I have the following subscription:

```js
this.nudgePauseConnectivity$.pipe(
    tap(() => console.log(1)),
    withLatestFrom(this.hotspotPausedState$()),
    tap(() => console.log(2)),
    filter(([nudgePause, connectionPaused]) => connectionPaused === enums.HotspotPausedStateEnum.FALSE),
    tap(() => console.log(3)),
    switchMapTo(this._store.pipe(select(this._hotspotSelectors.selectUsername))),
    tap(() => console.log(4)),
    switchMap(username =>
        this._cabinApiV2Service.subscriberService.getRemainingConnectivityAllowance(username)
    ),
    tap(() => console.log(5)),
    map(remainingConnectivityAllowance => SubscriberConnectivityAllowanceTransformer.transform(
        remainingConnectivityAllowance
    ))
).subscribe(() => {/* Do something */});
```

`nudgePauseConnectivity$` is a subject I use to cause the body of the observable to execute, like this:

```js
pauseConnectivity() {
    this.nudgePauseConnectivity$.next({});
}
```

`this._hotspotSelectors.selectUsername` is an NgRx selector, which if you haven't used NgRx in an observable that returns values from a store.

My problem is this: I thought that the expression would execute *once* for each value emitted from `this.nudgePauseConnectivity$`. I would expect to see in the console:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

However, it seems that even if `this.nudgePauseConnectivity$` does not emit a value, the execution of the expression begins if `this._store.pipe(select(this._hotspotSelectors.selectUsername))` emits a value, so I am seeing this sort of output in the console:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 4
>
> 5

I am thoroughly confused by this! I do not want the expression to ever begin executing in the middle: I would like the expression to execute only if `this.nudgePauseConnectivity$` emits a value, irrespective of the values of any expressions in the `switchMap`s or other high order observable operators later in the chain.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

switchMap doesn't cancel the subscription after the first emission. You should do that. We usually forget this because most of time we're dealing with 1 emission observable, like http client. As you have a stream that lives while your app lives, instead of:

```js
switchMapTo(this._store.pipe(select(this._hotspotSelectors.selectUsername))),
```

you could do (to *not* interrupt all the chaining from the `nudgePauseConnectivity$` - this will limit just the emissions from the `switchMap` to a single emission, but will keep the subscription to `nudgePauseConnectivity$` active):

```js
switchMap(() => this._store.pipe(
 select(this._hotspotSelectors.selectUsername), 
 take(1)
)
```

Or just put the `take(1)` in the chain after `switchMapTo` if you want to interrupt all the emissions after the first one (it will cancel de subscription to `nudgePauseConnectivity$` after the 1st emission):

```js
...
switchMapTo(this._store.pipe(select(this._hotspotSelectors.selectUsername))),
take(1),
...
```

It worth taking a look in other parts of your code to see if you're unsubscribing correctly form **all** the observables you're using (even those of angular forms).

Comment: This does not solve the problem because the `nudgePauseConnectivity$` observable will emit again eventually and I want the expression to execute again and emit a value for the subscribe block. Adding the code as you suggest means the subscribe block only executes once.

Comment: If you put the `take(1)` after the `select` (the first example) you'll get what you need.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thank you! I'm not really understanding how this means the switchMap emits one value for each run of the expression, and why that each run of the expression from the beginning "resets" this switchMap body so that it can again emit another value, but I will reread it a few times to see if I can get my head around it.